# Contact form: 401 - Unauthorized

Tags: php, html, forms, unauthorized

I am creating a contact form for a website but when I try a test message I am getting this error:
401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials

The website is: http://zimik-webdesign.com/contact_us.html

Here is the PHP:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Submitting...</title>

</head>

<body>

<?php
$First_Name = $_POST ['first_name'];
$Last_Name = $_POST ['last_name'];
$Email = $_POST['email'];
$Number = $_POST['phone_number'];
$Company = $_POST['company'];
$Country = $_POST ['country'];
$Message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="First Name: $First_Name
\n Last Name: $Last_Name
\n Email: $Email 
\n Number: $Number
\n Company: $Company
\n Country: $Country
\n Message: $Message";
$recipient = "tristan@ukbigbuy.com";
$subject = "Contact";
$mailheader = "From: $Email \r\n";
ini_set("sendmail_from","tristan@ukbigbuy.com");
mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Please try again.");
echo "Form Submitted.";
header("Location: http://www.zimik-webdesign.com/contact_us.html");
?>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is the html for the form:

```
<form id="contact_form" action="mail.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
<table border="0" align="center">
<tr>
<td rowspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"><label for="first_name">
<span class="b1" style="text-align:left;">First Name</span></label></td>
<td rowspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"><label for="message"><span class="b1" style="text-align:center;">Message</span></label></td>
<td rowspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
<td align="left"><label for="phone_number"><b1><span class="b1" style="text-align:left;">Phone Number</span></b1></label></td>
<td rowspan="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="first_name" class="text" id="first_name">
</td>
<td rowspan="7">
<textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="phone_number" class="text" id="phone_number">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><label for="last_name"><span class="b1">Last Name</span></label></td>
<td align="left"><label for="company"><span class="b1">Company</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="text" name="company" id="company"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="left"><label for="email"><span class="b1">Email</span></label></td>
<td align="left"><label for="country"><span class="b1">Country</span></label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" class="text" name="email" id="email"></td>
<td><input type="text" class="text" name="country" id="country"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td align="center"><input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit" form="contact_form" formaction="mail.php" formenctype="multipart/form-data" formmethod="POST" formtarget="_self" title="Submit" value="Submit"/></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

I checked the permissions as suggested by Raj and changed the owner permissions from write to read/write and also set the group permissions to read too, this has solved the issue.

Thanks to Raj for your help.

Comment: Could you please post your Apache configuration? There is nothing in your PHP code that could cause this issue.

Comment: What URl do you call when submitting the form, i.e.: what`s the value of the `action` attribute of the `form` tag?

Comment: Where do I find my apache configuration?

The action is: mail.php

Comment: where is your form code??

Comment: Shall I post the html for the form?

Comment: are mail.php and contact_us.html situated in the same directory??

Comment: Yes they are both in the root folder

Comment: once check the permissions for mail.php

Comment: The public permissions are set to read

Comment: The owner permissions where only set to write and not read, I changed them to read/write, and I also set group permissions to read. This has solved the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is answer is by Raj and all credit goes to him.

The problem was that the owner and group permissions where set to write only so I changed them both to read/write which solved the problem. Big thanks to Raj.

Comment: Do you have the command that was used in order to change the permissions?